# Show Overflow Text Aligned Vertically

Tags: excel, overflow

In an excel sheet I am wanting to align text vertically but the overflow text will not display. Merging cells and/or expanding the row height is not an option for my application.

Is there a setting that allows vertically aligned overflow text to be displayed?

Thanks!

Comment: I assume you want to display it by allowing the "overflow" text to display on a new line? If this is the case, click the cell and then click *Wrap Text* button from the *Home* tab.

Comment: I want the text to overflow into the cell above it. The text is rotated 90 degrees to be vertically aligned.

If it were horizontal, the text would overflow into the cell to its right if there were nothing in that cell. However, this doesn't work the same way when the text is rotated vertically.

Comment: Ah, OK, I see your point. Unfortunately, I'm not aware of a way to do this. Good question though. +1

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is by merging the cells together: Select the cell with the vertical text in it and all the cells you want the text to overlay, then, in the "Home" tab, under "Alignment", click "Merge and center". Not exactly an "overflow", but serves the same purpose.